# Different materials in SketchUp?

Tags: print-production, sketchup

I'm modelling a house using SketchUp. I noticed that some parts of the house have different colors while modelling, and these parts are not printed when I send the project to a 3D printer (figure below). I didn't change any parameter when I drew this roof, so what's happening here? Can I do something to fix this problem?

Thanks,

[image: The roof of this house has different color and, specifically this part, is not being printed.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3D model seems to contain separate surfaces. They may be placed like they were walls of a solid block, but SketchUP sees them as separate parts which have zero thickness. That happens easily if you for ex. try to put together separately drawn surfaces.

Your 3D printing process obviously cannot find what's the interior which should be filled when there's no tight solid block, only separate surfaces.

One way to get solids is to combine extruded, revolved, lofted, swept etc... solids by using Boolean operations and by splitting them with cutting planes. I'm afraid such possibilities are not available in free versions of SketchUP.

Without having your non-working model and without knowing your 3D print process only guesses are possible. Hopefully you are not trying to levitate melted plastics in the air,  but have proper supports parts below the floors in the printing.